# Unable to read all content in order of a word document (docx) in Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I've been trying to read all content (including tables, pictures, paragraphs) from a word document. I'm able to read tables and paragraphs using getBodyElementsIterator() but it doesn't read pictures present inside the document. 
Although I'm able to read pictures seperately using getAllPictures() but I need to read everything in order.

I've tried looking for XWPFPicture instance while looping inside getBodyElementsIterator() but I'm not able to find any image instance.

```
Iterator<IBodyElement> iter = xdoc.getBodyElementsIterator();
           while (iter.hasNext()) {
               IBodyElement elem = iter.next();
               if (elem instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
                  System.out.println("para - "+elem.getClass());
               } else if (elem instanceof XWPFTable) {
                  System.out.println("table - "+elem);
               } else if (elem instanceof XWPFPictureData){
                  System.out.println("picture - "+elem);
               } else {
                  System.out.println("else - "+elem);
               }  
            }
```

This is the output I'm getting.

```
paraorg.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@4d3167f4
paraorg.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@ed9d034
tableorg.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable@6121c9d6
paraorg.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@87f383f
paraorg.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph@4eb7f003
```

It contains paragraphs and tables but not any pictures

Comment: This question is lot to broad to answer here. Others have programmed whole libraries around the requirement "to read all content in order of a word document (docx) in Apache POI". See [XWPFDocumentVisitor](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/blob/master/thirdparties-extension/fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core/src/main/java/fr/opensagres/poi/xwpf/converter/core/XWPFDocumentVisitor.java).

Comment: I can give you some explanation why pictures can't be handled the same way as tables, etc. Pictures are not acutally *part* of the document.xml. All that's in the document is a *reference* to the picture data that's stored elsewhere, in a different xml file in the zip package. A library such as the Open XML SDK, that provides access to the entire zip package, could handle what you ask, but take a lot more coding. Apprently there are other libraries that can do as you ask ^^. But I thought you might like to understand the "why"...

Comment: @Cindy Meister: `Apache poi` also "provides access to the entire zip package".

Comment: @AxelRichter Good to know :-) Sometimes, when I read through comments, Q's and A's it's not clear to me that it can reach all the little corners...

Answer (score 3):

As told in comments already the question how to read all content in order of a word document (docx) in `apache poi` is much too broad to be answerable here. A `*.docx` is a `ZIP` archive in `Office Open XML` file format. It contains the `document.xml` for the document body. This is very complex `XML` which needs to be traversed. But that `document.xml` might contain references to other resources in the `*.docx` `ZIP` archive which then also needs to be traversed.

What I can provide is a template of how this traversing process could look like. It starts at [XWPFDocument](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html) and at first traverses all the [IBodyElement](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/IBodyElement.html)s in it. According to the found type of `IBodyElement` it does further traversing processes then.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.List;

public class WordReadAllContent {

 static void traversePictures(List<XWPFPicture> pictures) throws Exception {
  for (XWPFPicture picture : pictures) {
   System.out.println(picture);
   XWPFPictureData pictureData = picture.getPictureData();
   System.out.println(pictureData);
  }
 }

 static void traverseRunElements(List<IRunElement> runElements) throws Exception {
  for (IRunElement runElement : runElements) {
   if (runElement instanceof XWPFFieldRun) {
    XWPFFieldRun fieldRun = (XWPFFieldRun)runElement;
    System.out.println(fieldRun.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(fieldRun);
    traversePictures(fieldRun.getEmbeddedPictures());
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
    XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)runElement;
    System.out.println(hyperlinkRun.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(hyperlinkRun);
    traversePictures(hyperlinkRun.getEmbeddedPictures());
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
    XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun)runElement;
    System.out.println(run.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(run);
    traversePictures(run.getEmbeddedPictures());
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)runElement;
    System.out.println(sDT);
    System.out.println(sDT.getContent());
    //ToDo: The SDT may have traversable content too.
   }
  }
 }

 static void traverseTableCells(List<ICell> tableICells) throws Exception {
  for (ICell tableICell : tableICells) {
   if (tableICell instanceof XWPFSDTCell) {
    XWPFSDTCell sDTCell = (XWPFSDTCell)tableICell;
    System.out.println(sDTCell);
    //ToDo: The SDTCell may have traversable content too.
   } else if (tableICell instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
    XWPFTableCell tableCell = (XWPFTableCell)tableICell;
    System.out.println(tableCell);
    traverseBodyElements(tableCell.getBodyElements());
   }
  }
 }

 static void traverseTableRows(List<XWPFTableRow> tableRows) throws Exception {
  for (XWPFTableRow tableRow : tableRows) {
   System.out.println(tableRow);
   traverseTableCells(tableRow.getTableICells());
  }
 }

 static void traverseBodyElements(List<IBodyElement> bodyElements) throws Exception {
  for (IBodyElement bodyElement : bodyElements) {
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
    System.out.println(paragraph);
    traverseRunElements(paragraph.getIRuns());
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)bodyElement;
    System.out.println(sDT);
    System.out.println(sDT.getContent());
    //ToDo: The SDT may have traversable content too.
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFTable) {
    XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable)bodyElement;
    System.out.println(table);
    traverseTableRows(table.getRows());
   }
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String inFilePath = "./WordDocument.docx";

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(inFilePath));
  traverseBodyElements(document.getBodyElements());

  document.close();
 }

}
```

This is a working draft. I am sure, I forgot something.

Comment: Nice example, but bodyElements don't include some elemets, like comments or footnotes.

Comment: @Ermintar: Correct, but I told already: This is a working draft. I am sure, I forgot something. It is a start and of course you are free to improve and extend it.