# How to find and write a line of a .doc file via apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, java-6

I have a "replaceText" method that writes data to the generated file. This does not read the paragraph. You need to get a paragraph so that he can find the desired marker. I can’t understand that he receives the first - a paragraph or a text?

```
for (XWPFParagraph p : xdoc.getParagraphs()) {
        for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
            String text = r.getText(0);
            if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
                String msg = param.get(text.trim());
                if (msg != null) {
                    text = text.replace(text.trim(), msg);
                    r.setText(text, 0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFPoA.png)

Comment: Please add more information.. problem is not clear

Comment: As your screenshot shows, the first text top right is in a table. So you need gettig the table first. Try traversing all body elements using [XWPFDocument.getBodyElements-](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getBodyElements--) instead of only traversing the paragraphs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726756/unable-to-read-all-content-in-order-of-a-word-document-docx-in-apache-poi/57735780#57735780.