# I want to display embedded images between text using apache poi.Does anyone has any idea how this can be done?

Tags: java, apache-poi, documentviewer

Here is the code of extracting embedded images in word document using apache poi. I want to show the embedded images in between text using apache poi. Basically I want to make a document viewer in which I can view my document. If anyone has any other ideas on how to view documents in android please do share.

```
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileName));
 List<XWPFTable> table = doc.getTables();
 for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) {
   List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows();
   for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) {
     List<XWPFTableCell> cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();
     for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cell) {
       if (xwpfTableCell != null) {
         System.out.println(xwpfTableCell.getText());
         String s = xwpfTableCell.getText();
         for (XWPFParagraph p : xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs()) {
           for (XWPFRun run : p.getRuns()) {
             for (XWPFPicture pic : run.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
               byte[] pictureData = pic.getPictureData().getData();
               System.out.println("picture : " + pictureData);
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726756/unable-to-read-all-content-in-order-of-a-word-document-docx-in-apache-poi/57735780#57735780 for how to traverse the body of a `XWPFDocument` to get it's contents.

Comment: I'm able to traverse all the contents but I need to display the content in my android app do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: First decision would be: In what format should the content be displayed? Plain text format is not able displaying images.

Comment: I want to display the content in the same way it gets displayed in MS Office app or Google docs app. I can traverse the document and can find whether it's an image or text but I don't know how to display it like it's getting displayed in MS Office. Can you help please?

Comment: thanks but we want to include custom document viewer in our application. If you can suggest something it will be of great help.