# Trouble extracting all elements of docx TableCell in correct order with Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I need to extract all elements out of MS Word (docx file) inside XWPFTableCell and write them to a list of VOs in order of appearance.  My problem is - I cannot find a way to iterate through TableCell contents and detect when new element begins correctly.

Currently, I can successfully pull all elements, but not in order.  The result is always all paragraphs, then all tables or vice versa.

Current code is:

```
private List<CellVo> extractData(XWPFTableCell cell) {    
    List<CellVo> textList = new ArrayList<CellVo>(); // this array will hold all value objects for this TableCell
    int currPara = 1;

    for (XWPFParagraph para : cell.getParagraphs()) {           
        CellVo cellVo = new CellVo();   // this object has 2 properties: type of element (paragraph/table, etc), and its value 
        if (currPara <= cell.getParagraphs().size()) {  
            if (para.getNumFmt() != null) { // this is a list of some sort  
                cellVo.setProperty(para.getNumFmt());  // write the type of list here (decimal, bullet, etc) 
            } else {
                cellVo.setProperty("paragraph");
            }
            
            String editedString = Regex.replaceCharacters(para.getText());
            editedString = Regex.removeBrackets(editedString);
            cellVo.setValue(editedString);
        }           
        textList.add(cellVo);
        currPara ++; 
    }
        
    for (XWPFTable table : cell.getTables()) {          
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getRows().size(); i++) {
            CellVo cellVo = new CellVo();
            cellVo.setProperty("table");        
            XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(i);
            String cellText = String.valueOf(i);            
            for (int j = 0; j < row.getTableCells().size(); j++) {
                cellText += ("|"+row.getTableCells().get(j).getText());
            }
            cellVo.setValue(cellText);
            textList.add(cellVo);
        }
    }

    return textList;
}
```

The code above, as I said earlier, will extract all necessary data in correct format, but obviously it does one type, then the other.  Not in correct sequence.  I've tried working with .getBodyElements(), .getElementType(), .getPartType() etc, but cant seem to find a way around this problem.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Try traversing the `XWPFDokument` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726756/unable-to-read-all-content-in-order-of-a-word-document-docx-in-apache-poi/57735780#57735780. There the `traverseTableCells` calls `traverseBodyElements` again and this should traversing all elements in that table cell in correct order.

Comment: Axel, thank you very much!  That made things much clearer for me and I was able to reference your code to get this to work!  If you could post an answer, I'll mark it as correct!