# How to get footnote hyperlink while reading a Word document using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to convert a Word document to HTML. I have a Word document that has a footnote which includes an external hyperlink. I am not able to get the hyperlink URL for that hyperlink. Here is my code:

```
List<CTHyperlink> links = paragraph.getCTP().getHyperlinkList();
log.debug("Count of hyperlinks="+links.size());
for (CTHyperlink ctHyperlink : links) {
   String rId = ctHyperlink.getId();
   log.debug("rid="+rId);
   XWPFHyperlink link = document.getHyperlinkByID(rId);
   if(link!=null) {
      log.debug("link not NULL");
   }else {
      log.debug("link is NULL");
   }
}
```

From the above code, I see that in my case, the count of hyperlinks is 2. I am getting the rId correctly as "rId1" and "rId2" but link is always coming as NULL.

In the OOXML, I see that the hyperlinks in the document are stored in package name "/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" while hyperlinks in the footnote are stored in the package name "/word/_rels/footnotes.xml.rels". Probably that is the reason why my link variable is coming as NULL. But I am not sure how to get the hyperlink element from the footnote relationship package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If the `paragraph` in your code snippet is in a `XWPFAbstractFootnoteEndnote` then  it is in package part `/word/footnotes.xml` or `/word/endnotes.xml` and not in `/word/document.xml`. And `XWPFDocument.getHyperlinkByID` only gets the hyperlinks stored in `/word/document.xml`.

The solution depends on where the `paragraph` in your code snippet is coming from. This you are not showing.

But simplest solution would be to get the `XWPFHyperlinkRun` from the `XWPFParagraph` and then get the `XWPFHyperlink` from that `XWPFHyperlinkRun`. If the parent package part of the `XWPFHyperlinkRun` is not the `XWPFDocument` then  this must be done using underlying `PackageRelationship` since a hyperlink list only exists for `XWPFDocument` until now.

In [Unable to read all content in order of a word document (docx) in Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726756/unable-to-read-all-content-in-order-of-a-word-document-docx-in-apache-poi/57735780#57735780) I have shown a basic example for how to traverse a `Word`document. This code I have extended now to traverse footnotes and endnotes as well as headers and footers and to handle found `XWPFHyperlinkRun`s.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationship;

import java.util.List;

public class WordTraverseAll {
    
 static void traversePictures(List<XWPFPicture> pictures) throws Exception {
  for (XWPFPicture picture : pictures) {
   System.out.println(picture);
   XWPFPictureData pictureData = picture.getPictureData();
   System.out.println(pictureData);
  }
 }

 static void traverseComments(XWPFRun run) throws Exception {
  CTMarkup comr = null;
  if (run.getCTR().getCommentReferenceList().size() > 0) {
   comr = run.getCTR().getCommentReferenceList().get(0);
  }
  if (comr != null) {
   XWPFComment comment = run.getDocument().getCommentByID(String.valueOf(comr.getId().intValue())); 
   System.out.println("Comment from " + comment.getAuthor() + ": " + comment.getText());   
  }
 }

 static void traverseFootnotes(XWPFRun run) throws Exception {
  CTFtnEdnRef ftn = null;
  if (run.getCTR().getFootnoteReferenceList().size() > 0) {
   ftn = run.getCTR().getFootnoteReferenceList().get(0);
  } else if (run.getCTR().getEndnoteReferenceList().size() > 0) {
   ftn = run.getCTR().getEndnoteReferenceList().get(0);   
  }
  if (ftn != null) {
   XWPFAbstractFootnoteEndnote footnote =
    ftn.getDomNode().getLocalName().equals("footnoteReference") ?
     run.getDocument().getFootnoteByID(ftn.getId().intValue()) :
     run.getDocument().getEndnoteByID(ftn.getId().intValue());
   for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : footnote.getParagraphs()) {
    traverseRunElements(paragraph.getIRuns());   
   }
  } 
 }
 
 static void traverseRunElements(List<IRunElement> runElements) throws Exception {
  for (IRunElement runElement : runElements) {
   if (runElement instanceof XWPFFieldRun) {
    XWPFFieldRun fieldRun = (XWPFFieldRun)runElement;
    //System.out.println(fieldRun.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(fieldRun);
    traversePictures(fieldRun.getEmbeddedPictures());
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
    XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)runElement;
    //System.out.println(hyperlinkRun.getClass().getName());
    String rId = hyperlinkRun.getHyperlinkId();
    XWPFHyperlink hyperlink = null;
    if (hyperlinkRun.getParent().getPart() instanceof XWPFAbstractFootnotesEndnotes) {
     PackageRelationship rel = hyperlinkRun.getParent().getPart().getPackagePart().getRelationships().getRelationshipByID(rId);
     hyperlink = new XWPFHyperlink(rId, rel.getTargetURI().toString()); 
    } else if (hyperlinkRun.getParent().getPart() instanceof XWPFHeaderFooter) {
     PackageRelationship rel = hyperlinkRun.getParent().getPart().getPackagePart().getRelationships().getRelationshipByID(rId);
     hyperlink = new XWPFHyperlink(rId, rel.getTargetURI().toString()); 
    } else if (hyperlinkRun.getParent().getPart() instanceof XWPFDocument) {
     hyperlink = hyperlinkRun.getDocument().getHyperlinkByID(rId);
    }
    System.out.print(hyperlinkRun);
    if (hyperlink != null) System.out.println("->" + hyperlink.getURL());
    traversePictures(hyperlinkRun.getEmbeddedPictures());
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
    XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun)runElement;
    //System.out.println(run.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(run);
    traverseFootnotes(run);
    traverseComments(run);
    traversePictures(run.getEmbeddedPictures());
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)runElement;
    System.out.println(sDT);
    System.out.println(sDT.getContent());
    //ToDo: The SDT may have traversable content too.
   }
  }
 }

 static void traverseTableCells(List<ICell> tableICells) throws Exception {
  for (ICell tableICell : tableICells) {
   if (tableICell instanceof XWPFSDTCell) {
    XWPFSDTCell sDTCell = (XWPFSDTCell)tableICell;
    System.out.println(sDTCell);
    //ToDo: The SDTCell may have traversable content too.
   } else if (tableICell instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
    XWPFTableCell tableCell = (XWPFTableCell)tableICell;
    //System.out.println(tableCell);
    traverseBodyElements(tableCell.getBodyElements());
   }
  }
 }

 static void traverseTableRows(List<XWPFTableRow> tableRows) throws Exception {
  for (XWPFTableRow tableRow : tableRows) {
   //System.out.println(tableRow);
   traverseTableCells(tableRow.getTableICells());
  }
 }

 static void traverseBodyElements(List<IBodyElement> bodyElements) throws Exception {
  for (IBodyElement bodyElement : bodyElements) {
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
    //System.out.println(paragraph);
    traverseRunElements(paragraph.getIRuns());
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)bodyElement;
    System.out.println(sDT);
    System.out.println(sDT.getContent());
    //ToDo: The SDT may have traversable content too.
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFTable) {
    XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable)bodyElement;
    //System.out.println(table);
    traverseTableRows(table.getRows());
   }
  }
 }
 
 static void traverseHeaderFooterElements(XWPFDocument document) throws Exception {
  for (XWPFHeader header : document.getHeaderList()) {
   traverseBodyElements(header.getBodyElements());
  }   
  for (XWPFFooter footer : document.getFooterList()) {
   traverseBodyElements(footer.getBodyElements());
  }   
 }
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordHavingHyperlinks.docx"));

  System.out.println("===== Document body elements =====");
  traverseBodyElements(document.getBodyElements());
  
  System.out.println("===== Header and footer elements =====");
  traverseHeaderFooterElements(document);
   
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Axel. This is really really helpful.

Comment: Can you also provide an example of how to traverse a hyperlink inside a SDT? I have another Word document which has a hyperlink run inside a SDT. <w:sdt><w:sdtContent><w:hyperlink><w:r><w:t>Text</w:t></w:r></w:hyperlink></w:sdtContent></w:sdt> This is inside the document.xml package. Thank you.

Comment: @Harpreet: If that would be simple, I had included it in my example. But while `apache poi` gets `XWPFSDT` as a `IBodyElement` it does not provide access to underlying `CTSdtRun` or `CTSdtContentRun`. So no avail up to now using `apache poi`'s document traversing methods. One would must traverse the whole document on low level using `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*`.