# Java Apache POI: paragraph.getText() is empty

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have this code:

```
try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(
                Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath)));
        ) {
            List<XWPFParagraph> xwpfParagraphList = doc.getParagraphs();
            for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : xwpfParagraphList) {
                System.out.println(xwpfParagraph.getText());
                System.out.println("---------");
            }
}
```

I was working with different `docx` files and for this particular file, `getText()` method returns empty text.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fKxfcR9Kp0AONAw-90LznujwgfT6C4Ia/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112014729884365809454&rtpof=true&sd=true

What is wrong with this `docx` file?

Comment: Well Word paragraphs might be empty. This is nothing unexpected. What problem do you have with that?

Comment: @AxelRichter huh? but the docx is not empty. There is text in the docx, but the loop above prints nothing.

Comment: I had read it as "**one** `xwpfParagraph.getText()` returns empty text" and not **all**. But all text in your document is in a table. Only three empty paragraphs are beyond the table. So `doc.getParagraphs()` returns a list only containig empty paragraphs. So you need to traverse tables too. In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726756/unable-to-read-all-content-in-order-of-a-word-document-docx-in-apache-poi/57735780#57735780 I shown a working draft to get all content from a DOCX.